# How can i make foreground(focus) window with ffi in lua? If i know HWND of my window. I need code

Tags: winapi, lua, window, focus, ffi

I use lua(moonloader) for GTA San Andreas. And i need make my window in focus when i want.
Now i have only HWND of my window

```
ffi = require "ffi"

-- определяем там что-то шоб работало
ffi.cdef [[
    typedef int BOOL;
    typedef unsigned long HANDLE;
    typedef HANDLE HWND;
    typedef int bInvert;
    HWND GetActiveWindow(void);

    BOOL FlashWindow(HWND hWnd, BOOL bInvert);
]]

-- Полчаем айди окна
HWND = ffi.C.GetActiveWindow()
```

Comment: [SetFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualc/ms646312(v=vs.90))

Comment: `SetFocus` used to be the way to go. In 16-bit Windows. Decades ago. In 32-bit Windows (and 64-bit), input has been virtualized to implement preemptive multitasking. At any given time, zero or more windows can have input focus. Setting the focus doesn't make any given window the foreground window, though. Which is apparently, what the OP is trying to accomplish. I'm not sure that's really what they *want*, but it seems to be what they are asking for.

Comment: there is SetForegroundWindow but whether that will do what you want depends on what is going on regarding lua and GTA and what you are trying to do. SetForegroundWindow will, for example, not allow an arbitrary background process to make an arbitrary window in another process the foreground window.